# Set interrupt on /dev/mem access

Tags: c++, linux, kernel, arm, embedded-linux

Is there any way to set an interrupt on specific physical address in /dev/mem in ARM Linux, In a way that, if an application tried to write in selected address, rather than write operation it calls my function?

---

**Clarifications**
The Technique introduced by Sam here (write_mem() and read_mem()) do not work. I will add further detail incase somebody can provide an answer.

I want to control the I/O communication between an application and physical address. Unfortunately the Application controls the I/O directly without using driver (by mapping the physical memory an assigning value to the mapped memory e.g. *value-in-mappedaddress = 0x1F). I want to monitor and even alter the values the application writes to the physical memory.

There are three ways coming to my mind to do this:

1. Setting a hardware breakpoint in the physical memory (I can not debug the application)
2. Altering the Page table so every time application requested a mapped memory I send its write request to somewhere else.
3. Directly change the values in mapped address by setting software breakpoint in the mapped address (application use mmap2() to map the application)

So now I have to use one of this ways, which until now I did not have success on any of them.

Comment: This seems quite weird. Could you say what you want to *achieve*?

Comment: Is this for troubleshooting / debugging or for an actual production-code mechanism?

Comment: You could use the *mm* layer and cause a fault when accessed and/or use hardware breakpoint features (or embedded trace).  It is probably non-standard; so I don't know if you mean theory or practice?  The last two comments are specifics of the first...

Comment: @domen it is called XY problem, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: Take a look at [write_mem()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L158) function. It's being called when you are writing to `/dev/mem`. You can modify it in a way you described in your question, should do the trick (i.e. add checking if writing happening to address of interest, and if yes -- do something).

Comment: @domen Hi Domen, I am simply trying to write a educational malware which control I/O and do Man in the Middle Attack in I/O level. For example, your user level application request the I/O status, and kernel read the state in /dev/mem address, and return the result to the software.

Comment: @sam Thank you Sam. I will hook this function and see what will happen, Also do you know something similar for read operation as well?

Comment: @SamaAzari Yeah, it's [read_mem()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L98). Take a look at [mem_fops](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/char/mem.c#L725) struct for the whole list.